# PowerShell: Passing Credentials to CQD (Teams)

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I need to pass Credentials to Powershell for CQD.
(CQD is the Office 365 "Call Quality Dashboard" for Teams).
I tried using the script from https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CQDPowerShell/2.0.0/Content/CQDPowerShell.psm1 or https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/need-connection-uri-for-creating-a-cqd-powershell/f3c9e340-bdac-47c9-af52-d47d6df49fca
But how do I bypass the login/password prompt and pass the credentials seamlessly to Powershell?

Here is my script:

```
function Get-CQDToken ([string]$client_id)
{
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
  $resourceUrl = $WebResource
  $redirectUrl = "https://cqd.teams.microsoft.com/spd/"
  $nonce = [guid]::NewGuid().GUID
  $url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&redirect_uri=" +
  [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($redirectUrl) +
  "&client_id=$client_id" +
  "&prompt=login" + "&nonce=$nonce" + "&resource=" + [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($WebResource)

  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

  $form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{ Width = 440; Height = 640 }
  $web = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser -Property @{ Width = 420; Height = 600; Url = ($url) }
  $DocComp = {
    $Global:uri = $web.Url.AbsoluteUri
    if ($Global:Uri -match "error=[^&]*|access_token=[^&]*") {$form.Close()}
  }

  $web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = $true
  $web.Add_DocumentCompleted($DocComp)
  $form.Controls.Add($web)
  $form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
  $form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

  $Script:TokenLifeTime = [Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString(($web.Url -replace '^.*?(expires_in.+)$','$1'))['expires_in']
  $Script:Token = [Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString(($web.Url -replace '^.*?(access_token.+)$','$1'))['access_token']
  
  return ('Bearer {0}' -f $Script:Token)
}

$userName = "aaron"
$password = "Password_1234" 
$configRest = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://cqd.teams.microsoft.com/repository/clientconfiguration" -Method Get -SessionVariable WebSession -UserAgent "CQDPowerShell V2.0"
$WebResource = $configRest.AuthLoginResource
$AADBearerToken = Get-CQDToken $configRest.AuthWebAppClientId
$WebSession.headers.Add('Authorization',$AADBearerToken)
```

Comment: Cqd don't have parameter of -credential. It have direct mechanism. For passing credentials please go through this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/add-credentials-to-powershell-functions?view=powershell-7.1

Try with latest cqd tools https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CQDTools/2.0.0-beta

Comment: The get-cqddata in 2.0.0 does not accept credentials. Instead it needs a Token. That's why I am calling the Get-CQDToken. This token function, specifically calls the URL ($url) that prompts for creds. If this url can take in creds as variables, then what should it be modified to. See script above

Answer (score -1):

Please go through this ms docs.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/how-to-make-source-code-from-cqdpowershell-cmdlet-acquiring/m-p/1325146

While we need to have the code running indefinitely without the user interaction. Access code works for 1hr only again have to intract again. So it won't work

If they have their own datamart and want to build their own reporting UI and customize their own reports etc - create a subscription to the call records API Working with the call records API in Microsoft Graph - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs and use that to stream the call records into their own system.

Comment: All users on the link you posted have the same problem as the one I posted. The objective here is to formulate a way to bypass the manual interaction

Comment: @hdsouza, were you able to figure this out? I have the same requirements.

Comment: Sorry. No luck. I had opened a Microsoft ticket as well at the time as well as a feature enhancement request. Although Microsoft placed it in work-in-progress and mentioned it would be done only if several clients were interested.